# How to get specific element out of returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a specific element out of returned data.
here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get("data.html",function(data){
                console.log($(data).filter("#app span").html());
            })
        })
    </script>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="a">AAAAAA</div>
    <div class="b">BBBBBB</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And data.html:

```
<div id="app">
    <span>Message</span>
    <div>vjfjdjdj</div>
</div>
```

I need to get `Message` inside the `<span>`, but it returns nothing. Any idea?

Comment: it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the posted markup the top level element is the `#app` element, `filter` method doesn't filter the descendant elements of the top level elements, you should use `.find()` or `.children()` method:

```
console.log($(data).find("span").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should return in your console all `span` data

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("data.html",function(data) {
        var content= $('<div />').html(data);

        console.log(content.find('#app span').html());
    })
})
```